# How to select a particular slide from a presentation using powershell?

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I need a slide object that takes a particular slide according to the slide number given. 
I used slides.select method but it threw an error that select method is not available for that object.
Can anyone help ? 
Thanks in advance :) 
Following is the part of the code where I'm stuck

```
    if($slide_count -lt $slide_no)
{
# In case the base ppt does not have the number of slides already
    for($j=$slide_count;$j -le $slide_no;$j++)
   {
    $slide = $my_ppt.Slides.Add($my_ppt.Slides.Count + 1, 15)
   }
}
else
{
   $slide=$my_ppt.Slides.select($slide_no)
}
```

The else part is where I need help. I tried the actual syntax which threw the same error at the Slides part itself.

```
      $slide=$my_ppt.Slides($slide_no).select
```

Comment: share your code with us.

Comment: @MartinBrandl Sure.. I've changed the description

Comment: The PPT object model allows you to refer directly to slide objects w/o having to select them (which makes your code faster and more reliable).  I don't know PowerShell, but I'd suggest trying $slide=$my_ppt.Slides($slides_no) then manipulating the $slide object